# Combining Two Columns for "Order By"

Tags: php, mysql

Please help, I am very confused by this problem, have tried several times but still failed

Here's the data in my database:

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |   title   |   created     |   modify      |
|---------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   test1   |   2020-03-11  |       -       |
|   2   |   test2   |   2020-03-12  |   2020-06-28  |
|   3   |   test3   |   2020-03-13  |       -       |
|   4   |   test4   |   2020-03-14  |   2020-06-17  |
|   5   |   test5   |   2020-06-27  |   2020-06-25  |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

How do you combine the two columns above into one so the results look like this:

**Results:**

- test1  (2020-03-11)
- test3  (2020-03-13)
- test4  (2020-06-17)
- test5  (2020-06-27)
- test2  (2020-06-28)

The code I use:

```
$Q = $conn->query(SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY created ASC, modify ASC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

The results are not as expected. Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Is the `modify` value `NULL` for `test1` and `test3`?

Comment: @Nick No, if the article has not been edited, the `modify` column automatically contains `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: Then you just need to sort by modify and then created

Comment: there are two columns, I want to sort them, how do I do that. if only from the `modify` column, then how about the `created` column?